# modular alzebra

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Like alzebra can I write the following?

**1.(a+b+c+d+. . .n) % m = (a%m) + (b%m) + . . . +(n%m).**

**2.(a*b*c*d*. . .n) % m = (a%m) * (b%m) * . . . *(n%m).**

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The operation $a\mathbin{\%}m$ returns the remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$ (where $m\ne0$), so a number between $0$ and $|m|-1$ (including bounds). However, the sum of two remainders can very well be greater than $|m|-1$.

A counterexample with $a=4$, $b=5$ and $m=3$:
\begin{align}
&(4+5)\mathbin{\%}3=9\mathbin{\%}3=0\\[6px]
&(4\mathbin{\%}3)+(5\mathbin{\%}3)=1+2=3
\end{align}

What is true is that
$$
(a+b+c+\dots+n)\mathbin{\%}m=
\bigl((a\mathbin{\%}m)+(b\mathbin{\%}m)+(c\mathbin{\%}m)+\dots+
  (n\mathbin{\%}m)\bigr)\mathbin{\%}m
$$
and similarly for multiplications. In other words, you need to apply the mod operation once more.